# Django database keeps vanishing on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, migration

I have a Django project that is live on Heroku.

I'm trying to create a superuser on remote, but I get: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user`

So I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` and get the expected response.

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ MyWebsite... up, run.5296 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  ...
```

But when I run `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuse`, I get the same old `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user`

No matter how many times I run `migrate`, the table just seems to vanish right after. Any ideas on whats going on? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess here matches the comment by Fasial. It seems like you are using SQLite as your Django database.

Since the servers on heroku are reused and restartet all the time, you can't rely on local data being there all the time. For example, your `heroku run ..` command is running on a different server than your `web` dyno.

The way to go here is to switch to a different database like PostgreSQL, which Heroku also offers.

An example that works with django and heroku you find [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).